# Find text between two strings in data

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings

I download a page to get it's source code. I then extract the first segment of the page that is between two strings that appear in the source code more than once.

How can my code be improved?

```
url = "https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/lancamento/apartamento+venda+vl-mariana+zona-sul+sao-paulo+sp+ibirapuera-boulevard+mofarrej-empreendimentos+246m2-391m2/ID-16760/?contato=0"

sourcecode = requests.get(url)
r = sourcecode.text

string1 = '","billing":"'
string2 = '"},"createdDate":"'

start = re.findall(string1, r)
start = start[0]

end = re.findall(string2, r)
end = end[0]

text= r[r.find(start)+len(start):r.rfind(end)]

print(text)
```

Comment: I have edited your question to improve the readability. If I have made any mistakes please feel free to edit to fix it. :)

Comment: Could you provide us an example of what `r` or `sourcecode.text` is? Unfortunately I don't have access to the site to get it myself. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide examples of how the code should be used which demonstrate that it works as expected. I don't believe this works, because it will always find the last instance of `string2` despite your attempts to achieve otherwise.